# How to translate metatag token into text?

Tags: nodes, tokens, meta-tags

I'm trying to get the data from meta tag using node_load and for some reason when is using the default field, which is Token it gives me this ugly array.

[image: ugly array]

Instead of **title** and **description** that contain the strings.

Do you know how I can translate the Token into the actual text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running a very out-dated Metatag version. Once I update to the latest version I was able to run `metatags_get_entity_metatags` and get all the meta tag the way it supposes too.